# How to use variables of data function on VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a stupid problem with VueJS. I'm new with VueJS. I want to access and change variables of data function. However I couldn't do it.

**Line which is getting error:**

`console.log('item: ' + this.item);`

**Error is here:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

**Here is my code:**

```
data: function(){
    return {
        item: 69,
        file: 0
    };
},

methods: {
    toggle: (elementId = 0, type = 'item') => {
        console.log('element ID: ' + elementId);
        console.log('type: ' + type);
        console.log('item: ' + this.item);

        switch (type) {
            case 'item':
                break;
            case 'file':
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log('item: ' + this.item);` this is not an error

Comment: Share the error message too.

Comment: Ok guys, Post was updated as you wish.

Comment: Try this.$data.item to access the data.

Comment: @ThomasKleßen unfortunately, got the same error for $data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toggle(elementId = 0, type = 'item') {}` instead of `toggle: (elementId = 0, type = 'item') => {}`.
arrow function assigns `this` to its parent's `this` of the scope.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods